Deleting the data in the textedit when focusing on another object
I have this problem. I list the data in two different columns in the database in the combobox (CompanyName and CompanyCode). Then when I select the data from here, I print the CompanyName to cmbFirms, and I print the CompanyCode to txtFirmaKodu(edittext). But when I click on a different object, the CompanyCode I printed to txtFirmaKodu is deleted.
 private void FrmKullanicilar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    using (var context = new NetContext())
    {
        // Firmalar tablosundan verileri alın
        var firmalar = context.Firmalar.ToList();

        // Firmaları FirmaItem türüne dönüştürerek ComboBox'a ekleyin
        var firmaItems = firmalar.Select(f => new FirmaItem { FirmaAdi = f.FirmaAdi, FirmaKodu = f.FirmaKodu }).ToList();

        // ComboBox'a FirmaItem nesnelerini ekleyin
        cmbFirmalar.Properties.Items.AddRange(firmaItems);
    } 

       GetAll();
    }

     private void Binding()
     {
         txtAdı.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "Adi");
         txtSoyadi.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "SoyAdi");
         txtMail.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "Mail");
         txtTelefon.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "Telefon");
         cmbFirmalar.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", _entity, "FirmaAdi");            
          txtFirmaKodu.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "FirmaKodu");            
         txtKullaniciAdi.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "KullaniciAdi");
         txtSifre.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, "Sifre");
    
     }
 

    private void cmbFirmalar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (cmbFirmalar.SelectedItem != null)
         {
             // ComboBox'tan seçili öğeyi alın
             var selectedItem = cmbFirmalar.SelectedItem;
    
             // Seçili öğenin FirmaItem türünde olduğundan emin olun
             if (selectedItem is FirmaItem)
             {
                 FirmaItem selectedFirma = (FirmaItem)selectedItem;
                 // ComboBox'ta sadece FirmaAdi görüntülendiği için, sadece FirmaAdi'ni ComboBox'a ve FirmaKodu'nu txtFirmaKodu TextBox'ına yazdırın
                 cmbFirmalar.Text = selectedFirma.FirmaAdi;
                 txtFirmaKodu.DataBindings.Add("Text", _entity, selectedFirma.FirmaKodu.ToString());
                 txtFirmaKodu.Text = selectedFirma.FirmaKodu.ToString();
             }
         }
    
     }

 

    namespace NetKYS.Entities.Services
    {
        public class FirmaItem
        {
            public string FirmaAdi { get; set; }
            public int FirmaKodu { get; set; }
    
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{FirmaAdi} - {FirmaKodu}";
            }
        }
    }

